# Find and select Range based on a value

Tags: excel, vba

I have to sum up a column C. (A filtered column to be clear)
That went well and I saved the solution in the variable "sum".
Then I have to calculate 80% of it. So --> sum = sum*0,8

Now to my problem:
The column is sorted from largest to smallest.
And let's say the sum for the column is 650.000
I have to find and save the range where the sum of the range is the nearest to 650.000 (it can be +-5000)
E.G. the range in column C is C1:C50 - and 80% is from C1:C33

Or it'd be also possible if I can find the row where the sum from above until this row is near my value. Then I'd delete everything underneath this row.

I literally have no idea how to do this since I'm also not that good in VBA

Comment: Please post the code you have so far ... this makes it much easier for others to amend / add to that code - see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and I suggest you take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Also please clarify your question: if the sum of the column is 650,000 and the Range is C1:C50 then 'the Range that is nearest to 650,000' is that same Range. I think you mean 'the Range that is nearest to 80% of 650,000 starting from the top of the Range'?